What if something goes wrong during the seven minutes of terror?
We all know that NASA has sent rovers to Mars for several years. And, during the last 7 minutes, each rover follows the EDL (Entry, Descent, Landing) maneuver. I believe this process is completely autonomous due to the signal delay between Mars and Earth. But what if something like the opening of a parachute or the thrusters malfunction? Can the mission directors at NASA do anything?

I find this question confusing. You clearly know that there's a comms delay longer than the whole process, so ... what is it that you're imagining the directors could do? To put it another way ... what was surprising/new about the answer that Erin provided?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

No. By the time that NASA receives the signals from the spacecraft indicating that EDL has started (i.e. some indication of entry interface), whatever has happened has already happened. That's the reason for the terror--it's a dynamic phase of the flight, and either you've done your job AND gotten lucky and it all goes right, or you haven't and it doesn't.
See for example the video Curiosity's Seven Minutes of Terror. From the transcript:

From the top of the atmosphere, down to the surface-
It takes us seven minutes.
It takes 14 minutes or so for the signal from the spacecraft to make it to Earth-
thats how far Mars is away from us.
So, when we first get word that weve touched the top of the atmosphere, the vehicle has been alive...
(music intensifies- heavier percussion)
or dead, on the surface, for at least seven minutes.


Not "already happened"! It happens outside of our lightcone.

@fraxinus So it's "already happened", "currently happening" or "will happen", depending on our frame of reference (and from ours, relatively-stationary on Earth, it already happened). But it's outside our future light-cone, so from the perspective of doing something about it, it might as well have already happened.

@fraxinus that's a valid way of looking at it, but it's one I seldom prefer as an aerospace engineer

@ErinAnne The light-time between planets varies depending on where both of them are in orbit, though. At the closest approach, the light-time between Earth and Mars is just about 3 minutes, I believe, and the average distance is ~12 minutes. Even at closest approach, it wouldn't really help, because you have to double that time to get a message and bounce a command back, so it's still functionally impossible to do anything useful. If something has gone wrong at the very start of entry, you'd be able to get a command through just about the time the landing rockets are firing.

@DarthPseudonym Because of the way transfer orbits work, orchestrating a landing when Earth and Mars are closest is either very very expensive or very very slow. An efficient flight begins when Earth and Mars are closing their distance, and the landing is when Earth and Mars are opening their distance again. See this illustration.

@DarthPseudonym I didn't coin the term "seven minutes of terror."

@fraxinus arguing with relativity is not really needed here, as the involved speeds are all significantly non-relativistic. In both our and the lander's point of reference it's in the past, and there is no useful frame of reference where it would be in the future.

@ErinAnne The 'seven minutes' is how long reentry and landing takes, it has nothing to do with the light delay other than that the light-time means humans have no meaningful input.

@Schwern No argument here. Just pointing out that Mars was 14 minutes away at the time of Curiosity's landing and not like permanently. I will acknowledge that I was thinking Erin said it was 14 minutes, but that number was actually only in the quote. I blame Sunday Afternoon for this.

Aside: First time I've seen weve in professional text - or should I say Ive.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I noticed that too; it's an automatic-transcription artifact, obviously, but NASA isn't giving its videos the same amount of care as a modestly-successful Youtuber. and it may be required by law to try harder than that tbh; I'm not sure.

@chux-ReinstateMonica The transcript has problems with quotes apparently, there's also a numbers of thats and its and probably more.

@Schwern And if we cannot orchestrate a landing when the planets are closer to each other, the other solution would be to make a different type of landing, one which lasts much longer than 7 minutes. However, I'm reasonably certain that it would result in a much heavier and more expensive lander, requiring a much bigger rocket, and a lot of added complexity, which will add more failure modes, or will be much more expensive, or both.

No, there is nothing they can do if anything malfunctions during the entry, descent, and landing (EDL) phase.  The spacecraft is entirely on its own.  After landing, they have the opportunity to intervene if things are going wrong; for instance, when Mars Pathfinder landed, it was in a crisis -- the computers were going into safe mode, preventing it from deploying its solar panels and recharging its batteries.  This would've ended the mission almost immediately.  They had to work very fast to figure out what was wrong and solve the problem, which they were able to do.  But for EDL itself, there is no chance to help the spacecraft out -- it's gotta do everything on its own.
If any one of a hundred or more things fails to happen exactly right (the spacecraft isn't oriented correctly for entry, counterweights aren't ejected at the right moments, the drogue chute doesn't deploy, the main doesn't deploy, the backshell doesn't come away, the heat shield refuses to fall off, airbags don't inflate, braking rockets don't fire, braking rockets cut off too soon, cable cutters don't blow, etc.), the whole thing will fail.  It may miss the planet, it may explode, it may crash, or it may do everything exactly right and still end up stuck up against a boulder and fail to deploy.  (That's more or less what's believed to have happened to Beagle 2, based on MRO imagery.)
At that point, all they can do is study whatever telemetry they got, try to figure out what went wrong, and learn from it so they can make the next spacecraft work better.

Does this add anything to the accepted answer? It already explained No and Why.
